# Set height constraint on one of stackview items

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a stackView with 4 items and I want to set width and height of todayLabel in the stackView programmatically. How can I do that? I already tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
 todayLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
 todayLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Thank you very much for your help and this is my code:

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [todayDate, todayLabel, contentTextView, readMoreLabel])

stackView.axis = .vertical

stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally

stackView.spacing = 5

stackView.anchor(top: viewForImageAndLabel.bottomAnchor, left: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, bottom: shareButton.topAnchor, right: safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 15, paddingBottom: 10, paddingRight: 15, width: 0, height: 0)
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: That cannot work with `.fillProportionally`.

Comment: Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Show an image of what you want to achieve.